# OpenCV Python StereoCalibrate error

Tags: python, opencv

I am still using the old python CV interface as there is other code I do not want to migrate to the new python CV2 interface. When using the stereocalibrate function, I already have all my intrinsic camera parameters ready when I did a separate calibration of both my cameras using the cameraCalibrate function. I only want to find the R, T, E, and F matrices.

I am getting the error:

```
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

The following code is posted here:

```
import cv
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
from sys import getsizeof
import time

imagePoints = []
objectPoints = []
pointCounts = []

positions = 10

K1 = np.asarray([(  2303.88696,   0.00000000,   315.330859),
            (  0.00000000,   2303.75915,   234.229586),
            (  0.00000000,   0.00000000,   1.00000000)])

K2 = np.asarray([(  2294.70130,   0.00000000,   320.751796),
            (  0.00000000,   2293.85357,   240.760682),
            (  0.00000000,   0.00000000,   1.00000000)])

distcoeffs1 = np.asarray([( -7.42497976e-03,   3.74099082e+00,  -1.81154814e-03,  3.65969196e-04)])

distcoeffs2 = np.asarray([(  4.05620881e-03,   3.27334706e+00,  -5.00835868e-04,  1.56068477e-03)])

imageSize = (640,480)

R = np.asarray([(0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.)])
T = np.asarray([(0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.)])
E = np.asarray([(0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.)])
F = np.asarray([(0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.)])

images = range(0,positions)
for numberofimages in images:
    print numberofimages
    temp_output = []
    temp_coord = []

    f_output = file('/home/Desktop/output_stereo/output_cam1_%d.txt' %numberofimages, 'r')
    f_coord = file('/home/Desktop/output_stereo/coord.txt', 'r')    

    for line_output in f_output:
        row_output = line_output.split()
        temp_output = temp_output + [row_output]

    for line_coord in f_coord:
        row_coord = line_coord.split()
        temp_coord = temp_coord + [row_coord]

    count_output = range(0,len(temp_output))
    count_coord = range(0,len(temp_coord))

    for index_output in count_output:
        row_output = temp_output[index_output]      
        imagePoints = imagePoints + [(float(row_output[0]),float(row_output[1]))]

    for index_coord in count_coord:
        row_coord = temp_coord[index_coord] 
        objectPoints = objectPoints + [(float(row_coord[0]),float(row_coord[1]),0)]

    #pointCounts = pointCounts + [len(temp_output)]

imagePoints1 = cv.fromarray(np.asarray(imagePoints))
objectPoints = cv.fromarray(np.asarray(objectPoints))

imagePoints = []
for numberofimages in images:
    print numberofimages
    temp_output = []
    temp_coord = []

    f_output = file('/home/Desktop/output_stereo/output_cam2_%d.txt' %numberofimages, 'r')
    f_coord = file('/home/Desktop/output_stereo/coord.txt', 'r')    

    for line_output in f_output:
        row_output = line_output.split()
        temp_output = temp_output + [row_output]

    for line_coord in f_coord:
        row_coord = line_coord.split()
        temp_coord = temp_coord + [row_coord]

    count_output = range(0,len(temp_output))
    count_coord = range(0,len(temp_coord))

    for index_output in count_output:
        row_output = temp_output[index_output]      
        imagePoints = imagePoints + [(float(row_output[0]),float(row_output[1]))]

    pointCounts = pointCounts + [len(temp_output)]

imagePoints2 = cv.fromarray(np.asarray(imagePoints))
pointCounts = cv.fromarray(np.asarray(np.int32([pointCounts])))

cv.StereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, pointCounts, cv.fromarray(K1), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs1), cv.fromarray(K2), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs2), imageSize, cv.fromarray(R), cv.fromarray(T), cv.fromarray(E), cv.fromarray(F), cv.CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
```

The only argument that StereoCalibrate that is a tuple is imageSize, but I have already created it as a tuple. Every other argument is a CV array.

Which argument is causing the problem for me? The error does not give me any hints on which one.

Comment: just note, that they're doing away with the old cv api, next opencv version won't have it anymore

Comment: Yes I'm aware, there's just too much for me to do at the moment to switch everything to the new interface :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this you must set flags in the last argument. The error is not very helpful telling what is wrong.

It should be:

```
cv.StereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, pointCounts, cv.fromarray(K1), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs1), cv.fromarray(K2), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs2), imageSize, cv.fromarray(R), cv.fromarray(T), cv.fromarray(E), cv.fromarray(F), flags = cv.CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
```

Not:

```
cv.StereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, pointCounts, cv.fromarray(K1), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs1), cv.fromarray(K2), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs2), imageSize, cv.fromarray(R), cv.fromarray(T), cv.fromarray(E), cv.fromarray(F), cv.CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
```